# Blazor page calling an async task method OnClick

Tags: c#, razor, async-await, blazor

I have the following code, but it doesn't seem the await is working. Once an await call is called further down the line, it immediately returns. Any ideas?

```
<DialogButton Content="Upload" IsPrimary="true" OnClick="@(async Task () => await CustomAdvanceClick())" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the keyword `Task` should be there. `@(async () => await ...)`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my connection string was wrong. It had nothing to do with my code.